# Is instance property of Firebase a function?

Tags: firebase, flutter

https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/instance.html

```
static FirebaseMessaging get instance 
{
  return FirebaseMessaging._(app: Firebase.app());
}
```

`instance` word here does not have `()` after it, but it has `{}`.
Even while calling it we use: `FirebaseMessaging.instance`. No brackets.

Is this a function or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 things to understand why you can call `FirebaseMessaging.instance`:

### Getter

```dart
FirebaseMessaging get instance { /* ... */ }
```

First thing to understand is the concept of a getter defined by the keyword `get`. A getter is a method which does not take any arguments and which returns a value. In this case you have a getter named `instance` which returns an object of type `FirebaseMessaging`.

So a getter is technically a function which could also be written like this:

```
FirebaseMessaging getInstance() { /* ... */ }
```

But a getter is supposedly faster as it is dedicated to only retrieve values.

### Static method

Now how can you have access to this getter/method without needing an instance of the `FirebaseMessaging` object ? Well, it is simply because of the `static` keyword used for the getter:

```dart
static FirebaseMessaging get instance { /* ... */ }
```

Any method or variable declared within a class with the `static` keyword is the same for every instance of this class. Basically a single copy of this method will be shared among all instances of the `FirebaseMessaging` class. It allocates memory only once at the class loading.

So by calling `FirebaseMessaging.instance` you are calling a static method.